# Favoriting tag by clicking on star didn't reflect on favorite list on right

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

While toggling between favorite, ignored, and normal by clicking the star which appears by hovering the tag below the question, the previously favored tag would be removed. But toggling tag to favorite list doesn't append to the list But needs a refresh. Shouldn't it reflect instantly?

Comment: Maybe this is [tag:bug] instead of [tag:feature-request]?